# Waiting for ForEach-Loop to finish

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, foreach

im coding an Ionic-App which will show Products of a Wordpress/Woocommerce Shop. 
Now i want users to be able to favorite products, store them in local storage and show them also on another page.

Everything is working fine, but i got some problems with this ForEach-Loop in my "getAllFavoritePosts"-Function inside my Wordpress.service.ts file:

```
   getAllFavoritePosts(page = 1): Observable<any[]> {
   this.favUrl = this.url + this.auth + '&_embed' + '&include=0,';
//this is the loop i mentioned
   this.storage.forEach((value,key,index) => {
    this.favUrl = this.favUrl +  key + ',';
    })

    let options = {
      observe: "response" as 'body',
      params: {
        per_page: '12',
        page: ''+page
      }
    };
    return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.favUrl}`, options).pipe(
      map(resp => {
        this.pages = resp['headers'].get('x-wp-totalpages');
        this.totalProductsFavs = resp['headers'].get('x-wp-total');

        let data = resp['body'];

        for (let post of data) {
          post.media_url = post['images'][0]['src'];
        }
        return data;
      })
    )
  }
```

I need the Loop to be finished before the code after this will be executed.
Now the Url with the Ids of the favorited products is empty, because it is getting returned before the loop is fully executed.

If needed, this is the function in my home.ts where the function above is called:

```
 async loadFavs() {
    let loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Finde Deals'
    });
    await loading.present();
     this.wps.getAllFavoritePosts().subscribe(res => {
      this.countFavs = this.wps.totalProductsFavs;
      this.favs = res;
    loading.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

Already find smilar problems on this page, but still cant solve my problem.
Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: I think you can also add an async/await on your getAllFavoritePosts method.

Comment: Already tried to seperate the loop in another async method. Didnt work aswell..